# Alignment of apex sending email

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I have  body in the email in apex trigger:

```
strHtmlBody+='<b>text     &nbsp;:</b>' + OrderNumber +'<br/>';          
strHtmlBody+='<b>textlabel &nbsp;:</b>' + currentUser.name + &nbsp;test@g.com'<br/><br/>';
```

output is like:

```
text  :04577358
textlabel  :suresh test@g.com
```

**I want output like this what i have to align**

```
text       :04577358
textlabel  :suresh test@g.com -this email address should be display in the link in the body of email How? it should not display as text in the body of email
```

Comment: Use HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you need to use HTML table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>text</b></td>
        <td>OrderNumber</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>textlabel</b></td>
        <td>currentUser.name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the string create table, this will be like below

```
strHtmlBody += '<table>';
strHtmlBody += '<tr>'+
                    '<td><b>text</b></td>'+
                    '<td><b>'+OrderNumber+'</b></td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td><b>textlabel</b></td>'+
                    '<td><b>'+currentUser.name+' &nbsp<a href="mailto:test@g.com">test@g.com</a></b></td>'+
                '</tr>';
strHtmlBody += '</table>';
```

### Updates 2

```
strHtmlBody += '<table>';
strHtmlBody += '<tr>'+
                    '<td><b>text</b></td>'+
                    '<td><b>'+OrderNumber+'</b></td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td><b>textlabel</b></td>'+
                    '<td><b>'+currentUser.name+' &nbsp<a href="mailto:test@g.com">test@g.com</a></b></td>'+
                '</tr>';


if(!String.isBlank(currentUser.Phone)) {
    strHtmlBody += '<tr>'+ '<td><b>phone:</td></b>' + '<td>'+currentUser.Phone+'</td>'+ '</tr>';
} 
strHtmlBody += '</table>';
```

Comment: @user36188 you need to use anchor tag.. and if you want the current org url then `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()` to get the current org domain url

Comment: i dont want domain url, i am giving manually some email in the body that email should display as link thats all @Ratan how?

Comment: @user36188 check my updated answer. if you don't url and just want the link as test@g.com then I have updated code with anchor tag

Comment: How to overcome this issue with if statement @Ratan

Comment: @user36188 check my updates 2

Answer (score 1):

```
strHtmlBody+='<table><tr><td><b>text:</b>' + OrderNumber +'</td><tr/>';          
strHtmlBody+='<tr>textlabel:</b><a>' + currentUser.name + test@g.com'</a></td><tr/></table>';
```

Comment: test@g.com should display as link in the body of the email how@Rcs

Comment: try using href attribute in anchor tag and in href try to give your email as mailto=your mail e.g href="mailto:test@g.com"

Comment: Please add a bit more explanation as to why the fixed code works to present the details  in the required format to your answer - just a couple of lines of code is not very clear.